# In Season 3, how do T-Bag, Sucre, and Bellick come out of Sona?

Tags: prison-break

In the TV show, they said that T-Bag burned the Sona. But they never showed how he did that and what exactly happened there in the Sona. So how do T-Bag, Sucre, and Bellick come out of Sona?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As they showed in the season three last episode that, T-Bag burn down the SONA, and then sucre, Bellick and T-Bag came out of SONA.

Comment: Can you provide the episode name